# jQuery capturing last td of every row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each and every table row has one `TD` that holds a `<a>` link and one `TD` that holds a `form`. The following function makes the whole row act as a `<a>` link:

```
$('tr.altrow').click( function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest('[target="_blank"]').length) window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
}).hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
 });
```

The problem was that even when the TD hodling the form was clicked, the browser would call `<a>`. In order for that to work with suggestions I have came up with the following (Note: the form is always in the last `TD`):

```
 $('tr.altrow').find('td').last().click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

The previous function works, but it is only applied to the last TD of the very last row. But what I want to happen is that the function would be applied to each and every row of the table.

And here is the table in question:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="list-table">

        <tr class="altrow">
            <td>10</td>
            <td><a href="/customers/view/107">Customer </a></td>
            <td>
                <form action="/move/107/index" name="post_53d78bbe297a9999750228" id="post_53d78bbe297a9999750228" style="display:none;" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="82f8674d26a21bf73ae0ef89a60830cd71a9fbe4" id="Token60364222"/><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="d4431eb33bd022aaf88ee331efb5b9a47e305ab9%3A" id="TokenFields2025889457"/><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][unlocked]" value="" id="TokenUnlocked1072479614"/></div></form><a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { document.post_53d78bbe297a9999750228.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;"><img src="/img/move.png" alt="move" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>    
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="altrow">
            <td>10</td>
            <td><a href="/customers/view/108">Customer </a></td>
            <td>
                <form action="/move/108/index" name="post_53d78bbe297a9999750228" id="post_53d78bbe297a9999750228" style="display:none;" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="82f8674d26a21bf73ae0ef89a60830cd71a9fbe4" id="Token60364222"/><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="d4431eb33bd022aaf88ee331efb5b9a47e305ab9%3A" id="TokenFields2025889457"/><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][unlocked]" value="" id="TokenUnlocked1072479614"/></div></form><a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { document.post_53d78bbe297a9999750228.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;"><img src="/img/move.png" alt="move" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>    
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="altrow">
            <td>10</td>
            <td><a href="/customers/view/109">Customer </a></td>
            <td>
                <form action="/move/109/index" name="post_53d78bbe297a9999750228" id="post_53d78bbe297a9999750228" style="display:none;" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="82f8674d26a21bf73ae0ef89a60830cd71a9fbe4" id="Token60364222"/><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="d4431eb33bd022aaf88ee331efb5b9a47e305ab9%3A" id="TokenFields2025889457"/><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][unlocked]" value="" id="TokenUnlocked1072479614"/></div></form><a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { document.post_53d78bbe297a9999750228.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;"><img src="/img/move.png" alt="move" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>    
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector at this context,

```
$('tr.altrow td:last-child').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

[`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) would select the last element from the whole element collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('tr.altrow td:last-of-type').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get last `td`

```
$('tr.altrow').find('td:last')
```

Answer (score 1):

**[:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)**

```
  $('tr.altrow td:last-child').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation()
    });
```

by **[last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)**

```
 $('tr.altrow ').find("td").last().click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation()
    });
```